# cakephp functions like Set::combine in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cakephp, set

Are there already some javascript functions that do the same as the cakephp functions Set::combine and Set::classicExtract on client side in the browser?
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html

So that I can bring this array:

```
a = [
   {
        'User' : {
            'id' : 2,
            'group_id' : 1,
            'name' : 'Alfred'
         }
    },
    {
        'User' : {
            'id' : 12,
            'group_id' : 2,
            'name' : 'Albert'
         }
    }
]
```

with a function like

```
Set::combine(a, '{n}.User.id', '{n}.User.name')
```

into the format

```
a = {
  2 : 'Alfred',
  12 : 'Albert' 
}
```

for example. But it's not only for this simple example, I'm really looking for a library or something which can do it in a similar way to cakephp.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No. Javascript has nothing like this built-in.

Either you make these functions yourself, or you use a library such as [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) which provides a lot of utilities like this.

Answer (score 1):

I would ***love*** to see a JS equivalent to CakePHP's Hash class, but sadly after an hour of Googling, I cannot find anything...  Underscore.js and Sugar.js both have some filtering functions, but neither seem to work on multi-dimensional arrays.

In Cake I often do things like this...

```
Hash::extract($users, '{n}.User.Posts.{n}.Comments.{n}[published=1]');
```

If anyone knows a JS library that does this, would be very grateful for the tip.

---

**EDIT:  I have since found a few options** that allow this kind of querying of JSON data (with examples of the syntax they use).

- [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) (probably the most mature option)
  `automobiles[?maker == 'Honda' && year > 2009].model`
- [JSPath](https://github.com/dfilatov/jspath)

  `.automobiles{.maker === "Honda" && .year > 2009}.model`
- [json:select()](http://jsonselect.org/) (inspired more by CSS selectors)

  `.automobiles .maker:val("Honda") .model`
- [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) (inspired more by XPath)

  `$.automobiles[?(@.maker='Honda')].model`

JMESPath is my preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy in pure javascript:

```
result = {}
a.forEach(function(item) {
    result[item.User.id] = item.User.name;
})
```

I realize it's only a simple example, but the point is that javascript supports callbacks and first-class functions, and there's simply no need for magic like "{n}.User.name".

Comment: If there was no need for it, things like this would not exist. Using `Hash::extract()` on a complex structure like `{n}.User.Order.Product.name` is much easier than doing `foreach` many times. There is also no need to check if the variables actually exist. It also works for any structure when `foreach` would need to be done with each different structure, not DRY.

Comment: @dogmatic69: "If there was no need for it, it wouldn't exist" - I don't buy this logic. There are plenty of things, especially in computing, that are totally useless - but still exist.